# Why do I get huge memory and CPU spikes setting up the geocode tool

Tags: geocoding, arctoolbox, address

I am running the geocode tool against a database table which contains values for address, city, state, zip. I am using an address locator that I downloaded locally

http://gis.ats.ucla.edu/

Whenever I bring up the window for the tool and then select the address locator and then subsequently select the fields I get a huge CPU and Memory spike in ArcMap. Almost 1GB of RAM and 100% CPU. This last about 10 seconds for each field and the UI is completely unresponsive during this time. The process eventually works but it looks broken. Using Geocode Address from the right click menu doesn't give these problems, only the tool itself. It's not a huge problem but it makes demonstrations look very shaky.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of ArcMap and Service Pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU and memory usage goes up when you are specifying fields for the geocode addresses tool because ArcGIS is running a validation routine every time you change each field. It's checking to make sure that field is the proper type, etc. All geoprocessing tools work this way, although some tools do more validation than others.

This is especially bad for composite locators since each validation can cascade down into each participating locator, which is what I suspect is happening in your case.

I can't speak to why the geocoding wizard performs better, but my guess is that it's not doing the same validation as the geoprocessing tool.